# Update Bootstrap table with data already in it?

Tags: java, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Have a Bootstrap table that is populated using ajax and the bootstrap-table library. The table should be updated each time the client recieves a message from my server using socket, I have confirmed that my code executes on server message, but the table wont update..? Here is the complete javascript that is being ran in the browser:

```
url = "ws://192.168.1.116:8080";
ws = new WebSocket(url);

// event emmited when connected
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('websocket is connected ...');
        // sending a send event to websocket server
        ws.send('connected');
    }
    // event emmited when receiving message 
    ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
        alert("message from server");
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getqueue.php',
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("ajax success")
                    var response_Array = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $(function () {
                        $('#maintable').bootstrapTable({
                            data: response_Array
                        });
                    });

                },
                error: function() {
                    //something
                }
            })
    }
```

The table updates successfully the first time, but the new data is not inserted if the function is fired again. W

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="maintable" data-height="460">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="queue">#</th>
                <th data-field="nation_name">Nation</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**
Somewhat solved this by doing this:

```
$('#maintable').bootstrapTable("destroy");
                    $(function () {
                        $('#maintable').bootstrapTable({
                            data: response_Array
                        });
                    });
```

I remove the current table and create a new one that is populated with the new data. This is probably not optimal but it works well enough for my case.

Comment: are you saying you are getting data in `response_Array` ??. But table is not updating ?

Comment: What do you mean? The data is updating fine the first time i execute the code, but then it wont update to the NEW data.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I was just making cross check, with what you mentioned and I understand. Now, my question is, can get me JSON, which you get on first and second request ?? i.e. `response_Array` value on first and second request ?

Comment: please update your post with JSON

Comment: Yes I made an alert with the JSON each time it should update and the JSON does update as it should, just not inserting into the table...

Comment: Could you share sample JSON for first and second request to analyze ?

Comment: I might have solved this using this code: $('#maintable').bootstrapTable("destroy");                                                                 This removes the table and then creates a new one with the new data. This is ugly as hell if you ask me but it works.